# Knockout JS Binding a list of lists

Tags: knockout.js

I have a class containing a `List<List<MyObject>>`. I cannot find any examples of how to bind this List of Lists in Knockout JS. Is it possible?

What I've tried:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $data.ChildrenGrouped">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data.ChildrenGrouped[$index]">

    </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction and/or verify if it is possible?

Clarification:
This is an example of how my class is setup, not sure that it matters.

```
MyClass:
   Property1 Prop1 { get; set; }
   Property2 Prop2 { get; set; }
   List<List<MyClass>> ChildrenGrouped { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the ChildrenGrouped property on your JavaScript view model is an array of arrays, your view html would probably look more like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ChildrenGrouped">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Where $data on the inner loop is each entry (array) on the outer loop.

Comment: That seemed to easy of an answer haha. I'm not sure why I didn't try that first :( Thank you!